# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException for listener in web.xml with weblogic12.1.1

Tags: javascript, jakarta-ee

Im trying to upgrade the weblogic version from 10.3.3 to 12.1.1 for my application.

Im getting below mentioned error while deploying ear file in weblogic 12 which works fine with version10.

" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:[HTTP:101164] User defined class com.ab.util.session object is not a listener as it doesnt implement the correct interface."

Deployment is getting failed because of this error.If i comment out listener, deployment is success.

We make use of j2ee,struts,jdbc,js and javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionBindingListener.

I want to know that why im getting  " java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:[HTTP:101164] User defined class com.ab.util.session object is not a listener as it doesnt implement the correct interface"

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure that `com.ab.util.session` implements either `javax.servlet.ServletRequestListener`, or `javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionListener` or `javax.servlet.ServletContextListener`. (From the name, you most probably want to implement the `javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionListener`.)
2. Make sure that *NO JAR* in WEB-INF/lib contains the aforementioned class(es). If there is any "strange" classpath setting for the web application, also make sure that these classes (e.g. `javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionListener`) are *NOT* loaded by any other classloader besides the application server classloader.

Comment: Im making use of javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionBindingListener. I tried with javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionListener, deployment is successful. I think the issue is with interface " HttpSessionBindingListener " Is there much difference with HttpSessionBindingListener and HttpSessionListener.

Comment: The `HttpSessionBindingListener` is *NOT* a listener to be registered with `<listener>`. It is (from [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionBindingListener.html)) an interface that "causes an object to be notified when it is bound to or unbound from a session". A `HttpSessionListener` listens for the creation and destruction of sessions. Decide what is your case and use the appropriate object.